# How does caching selectors work under the hood

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

This is a pretty generaly question.
Is:

```
$el.siblings(".class");
```

better practice than

```
$("#id")
```

to access an element when $el has already been used before and is therefore already stored in a variable?

I am a bit unsure about this for a few reasons:

- id is apparently very fast;
- I am not entirely sure if the DOM needs to be traversed to get the sibling element when the original element got cached.

Following this question, I wonder how jQuery keeps reference to an internal DOM node when caching the selector (eg. `$el = $("#el");`). Although I know the syntax, I'm not sure about what happens under the hood (ie. how keeping the reference is programmed in JS).

Any formal confirmation on this?

Comment: I'd imagine the caching is precisely what you'd expect: a mapping of selectors to the results of getting the selectors' elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, jQuery just has a reference to the DOM element. Every time you do:

```
$("#el")
```

jQuery has to parse the selector to determine that it's looking for an ID, then call `document.getElementById("el")`. It saves the result of this in the jQuery object. If you do:

```
$el = $("#el");
```

and then use `$el` from then on, it doesn't have to do any parsing, and it doesn't have to call `getElementById()` to find the element. All the jQuery methods can simply use the instance variable that contains the saved DOM element.

Comment: I didn't expect that performance gain would come from parsing the selector rather than from traversing the DOM. Because even whether cached or not, it would appear that updating a value in the DOM (eg html()) always requires this. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking, is the DOM "indexed" in some way which allows direct access when elements are being cached, or is there a top-down "traverse" on every time an update is required?

Comment: The DOM is a data structure. DOM elements are references to the elements of that structure (essentially, they're pointers directly to the objects).